# Let $Z$ ∼ Geometric$(θ )$. Compute $P(5 ≤ Z ≤ 9)$

Tags: probability

Let $Z$ ∼ Geometric$(θ )$. Compute $P(5 ≤ Z ≤ 9)$

---

$$\sum_{k=5}^{9} (1-p)^kp = (1-p)^5p\frac{1-(1-p)^9}{1 - (1 - p)} = (1-p)^5 -(1-p)^9$$

The answer is $$(1-p)^5 - (1-p)^{10}$$

I read the formula for geometric series is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^k = ar\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Comment: I think you mean, in the question title, for the $\theta$ to be a $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend writing out the terms in the series and factoring.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=5}^{9}(1-p)^k p&= (1-p)^5p+(1-p)^6p+\cdots+(1-p)^9p \\
&= (1-p)^5p[1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+\cdots+(1-p)^4]\text{.}\tag{*}
\end{align}$$
Now, make use of the fact that
$$1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\text{, } r \neq 1\text{.}$$
Thus, assuming $p \neq 1$, we may write
$$1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+\cdots+(1-p)^4 = \dfrac{1-(1-p)^5}{1-(1-p)} = \dfrac{1-(1-p)^5}{p}\text{.}$$
From (*), we have
$$(1-p)^5p\cdot \dfrac{1-(1-p)^5}{p}=(1-p)^5[1-(1-p)^5]=(1-p)^5-(1-p)^{10}\text{.}$$